# Include gstreamer libs/headers in yocto sdk build

Tags: linux, gstreamer, yocto

I am building a Yocto SDK in order to cross compile a gstreamer plugin on Ubuntu targeted at the Raspberry Pi.  The sdk builds fine via `bitbake -c populate_sdk core-image-minimal` and I have all the relevant layers added, but the gstreamer libraries and headers are not included as part of the generated SDK.  What am I missing?

FYI:

```
Build Configuration:
BB_VERSION           = "1.46.0"
BUILD_SYS            = "x86_64-linux"
NATIVELSBSTRING      = "universal"
TARGET_SYS           = "aarch64-poky-linux"
MACHINE              = "raspberrypi4-64"
DISTRO               = "poky"
DISTRO_VERSION       = "3.1.27"
TUNE_FEATURES        = "aarch64 cortexa72 crc crypto"
TARGET_FPU           = ""
meta                 
meta-poky            
meta-yocto-bsp       = "dunfell:df86cc15d0a39d8d85747f7acc2c887cccfd9fa7"
meta-raspberrypi     = "dunfell:2081e1bb9a44025db7297bfd5d024977d42191ed"
meta-oe              
meta-python          
meta-networking      
meta-multimedia      = "dunfell:b8b0b06821d4d4df0cce4f07fa31a8ca1dd38f46"
```

Comment: I'm going to guess that `core-image-minimal`doesn't include gstreamer. You might have to make your own image type that does, or add it to your `local.conf`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do a quick test, you can add in your `local.conf` the gstreamer packages:

```
IMAGE_INSTALL += "gstreamer1.0"
# You can also add plugins to your image if you need them.
IMAGE_INSTALL += " gstreamer1.0-plugins-good \
                   gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad \
                   gstreamer1.0-plugins-base "
```

If you have a meta, add it in your image.

Comment: Yep, this was it - thanks. Specifically, I added:

IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " gstreamer1.0"

I'm new-ish to Yocto and it wasn't obvious since it appeared gstreamer was already part of the recipes since its folder existed in recipes-multimedia.

Also, thanks @pmacfarlane for pointing me in the right direction.